# Use VMWare with out a network?

Tags: networking, virtualization

I have a server running on VMWare that I need to communicate with using my computer. It works fine as long as I am hardwired to the network at work. If I try to work from home I am unable to ping the server. What is more interesting, is that it does not work if I am hardwired AND connected to the wifi at the same time. I have tried setting the connection to bridged and host-only with no success. Any ideas on how to make it work regardless of what network I am on? I am running Windows 7 on my computer and Windows Server 2008 on the virtual server.

Comment: Your connecting to the virtual server that is at your workplace and your computer is at home? Your question isn't clear as to where the server and client machine are.

Comment: The client is my laptop. The virtual server is running on VMWare on the same laptop.